# UITableView cell touch event only work on small part of the cell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a table view with multi cell.

All cells are handling the click listener very well except the two last cells. 
The first one only handles clicks when I press on the red highlighted part and the second does not.

Here is a screenshot. Can anyone please tell me how to know the reason for this problem knowing that all other cells are working fine.

**EDIT**

This is the cell element

[image]

[image]

and this is the code

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath{

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:newIndexPath animated:YES];

    KYDrawerController *elDrawer = (KYDrawerController*)self.navigationController.parentViewController;
    MainViewControllerObjc *viewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Forsa" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainController"];
    UINavigationController *navController=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:viewController];

    ForsaDataManager *sharedManager = [ForsaDataManager instance];
    SocialResponse *social = [sharedManager socialLinks];

    DrawerItem *test = [DrawerItem new];
    test = [self.dataSource objectAtIndex: newIndexPath.row];


    if ([test.tag isEqualToString:@"Login"]) {
        [self openLogin];
    } else if ([test.tag isEqualToString:@"Logout"]) {

        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [defaults setInteger:0 forKey:@"user-id-key"];
        [defaults setObject:@"" forKey:@"user-name-key"];
        [defaults setObject:@"" forKey:@"user-email-key"];
        [defaults setObject:@"" forKey:@"user-profile-key"];
        [defaults synchronize];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Forsa" bundle:nil];
            SplashViewController * secondViewController = (SplashViewController *)[sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"splash"];
            [self presentViewController:secondViewController animated:YES completion:nil];

        });

    } else if ([test.tag isEqualToString:@"Register"]){
        [self openRegister];
    } else if ([test.tag isEqualToString:@"Favorite"]){
        viewController.categoryId = -2;
        viewController.categoryName = @"التفضيلات";
    } else if ([test.tag isEqualToString:@"Facebook"]){
        [self openURL:social.facebook];
    } else if ([test.tag isEqualToString:@"Twitter"]){
        [self openURL:social.twitter];
    } else if ([test.tag isEqualToString:@"Youtube"]){
        [self openURL:social.youtube];
    } else if ([test.tag isEqualToString:@"Contact Us"]){
        [self openContactUs];
    } else if ([test.tag isEqualToString:@"About Us"]){
        int tag = 56;
        [self openAboutUs:(tag)];
    } else if ([test.tag isEqualToString:@"Terms"]){
        int tag = 57;
        [self openAboutUs:(tag)];
    } else if ([test.tag isEqualToString:@"Main"]){
        viewController.categoryId = -1;
    } else if([test.tag hasPrefix:@"Service_"]){
        NSString *string = [test.tag stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Service_" withString:@""];
        int catId = [string intValue];
        viewController.categoryId = catId;
        viewController.categoryName = test.title;
    }

    elDrawer.mainViewController=navController;
    [elDrawer setDrawerStateWithState:(DrawerStateClosed) animated:(YES)];
}
```

Comment: how you are getting the cell touch action ?

Comment: in the method - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath

Comment: can you show me your cell elements and code ?

Comment: @vivekDas please check my edit

Comment: @vivekDas I am using iPhone x simulator and xcode 9.4.1

Comment: Just check your tabelview's super view's frame, I think its super view's frame height is less, that is why bottom cells are not taking touch.

Comment: tried to put print statement inside about us and terms

Comment: I did, it only enter it when I press on a specific part of the two last cells and is working fine for the rest of cells

Comment: Have you tried on other devices?

Answer (score 0):

Since the test is in iPhone X , there is a touch area reserved instead of the home button that's removed ( bottom safeAreaLayoutGuide ) , you need to inset your table's bottom , or increase the constant value of the bottom constraint at least On iPhone-X

Comment: what do you mean by  inset your table bottom ?

Comment: i mean to make the bottom constraint with bottom safeAreaLayoutGuide or reset constant value of the bottom constraint to a higher value , you can verify that also by testing on another device like iPhone 8